# How to check for column attributes in postgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to SQL. Let say that when someone created a table like this in database named test1 of PostgreSQL:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME,
    contents VARCHAR(240) NOT NULL);
```

I make a query to the database and do not know how data in columns are stored.
Is there a query to return the stored definition of the columns in the users table or a method to check this ?

For example:
The result should return something like:

```
id column: SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
created_at: TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT CURRENT_TIME
...
```

Comment: Note that in modern Postgres versions, `identity` columns are recommended to be used over `serial`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `information_schema` for this

```
select * 
from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'users'
```

Comment: Thanks, mate. Your answer is absolutely what I need.